# Applescript, I am trying to make a list appear in a dialog box with only 3 of the total amount I have

Tags: macos, list, applescript

Applescript, I am trying to make a list appear in a dialog box with only 3 of the total amount of items. For example, I have a list of 5 possible items, I want the dialog box to display 3 random ones, but with no repeats. I don't know if I'm on the right track or not but Im stuck.

```
set myList to {"Apples", "Bananas", "Oranges", "Grapes", "Turkey"}

set r to some item of myList

set newList to (myList without r)

set t to some item of newList

set newerList to (newList without t)

newList
```

Comment: A better way to explain it is this:                                                                                 set mylist to {"Bob", "Brian", "Mark", "Joshua", "Sarah", "George"} as list
repeat
 display dialog some item of mylist
end repeat                                                                                                                                     I want to be able to do more than one random name, but not repeating. So, i don't want to get bob bob or sarah sarah george. I want to get bob sarah, or george brian mark, or however many I desire, just not repeated.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach than vadian's. The problem with vadian's script is that in theory the script could run forever, if the script continuously picks an item it has taken before. Therefore, it's better to have a solution that doesn't have collisions. It takes a little more effort, because after each time an item has been picked, the value has to be removed from the list. Since there is no simple command to do this in AppleScript, the script has to do it "manually".

The easiest way is to create a parallel list containing the indices of the input list, pick a random index in each iteration, and set it to a non-integer value. This way we ensure that the item is picked only once.

```applescript
set myList to {"Apples", "Bananas", "Oranges", "Grapes", "Turkey"}
set idxList to {}
-- first create a list with indexes
repeat with x from 1 to count myList
    set end of idxList to x
end repeat

set newList to {}
repeat 3 times
    -- pick a random index
    set theIndex to some integer of idxList
    -- add item to newlist based on picked index
    set end of newList to item theIndex of myList
    -- set the picked index to missing value so it will not be picked again
    set item theIndex of idxList to missing value
end repeat
newList
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a repeat loop which is executed until the maximum number of items is reached.

```
property maxItemsInNewList : 3

set newList to {}
set myList to {"Apples", "Bananas", "Oranges", "Grapes", "Turkey"}
repeat while (count newList) < maxItemsInNewList
    set r to some item of myList
    if newList does not contain r then set end of newList to r
end repeat
newList
```

Comment: This script can run forever because of the collisions. Especially when using larger lists where the result is `count newList = maxItemsInNewList`.

Comment: As mklement0 pointed out, it's more a matter of number of collision rises when size of `newList` will be closer to the size of `myList`

Answer (score 0):

To complement [dj bazzie wazzie's helpful pure AppleScript answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34435975/45375) with a solution that uses `do shell script` to call `perl`, which makes shuffling a list very easy:

```applescript
# Input list.
set myList to {"Apples", "Bananas", "Oranges", "Grapes", "Turkey"}

# Convert the list to a string with each item on its own line.
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "\n"  # ' perhaps restore original val. later
set myTextList to myList as text

# Set the number of random items to extract, without replacement.
set sampleSize to 3

# Call the shell to let Perl shuffle the lines, then 
# convert the lines back into a list and extract the first 3 items.
set randomSample to paragraphs 1 thru sampleSize of ¬
  (do shell script "perl -MList::Util=shuffle -e 'print shuffle <>' <<<" & ¬
    quoted form of myTextList)
```